# Researching Michael Patron (1897-1972) and Genia Zeimer (1900-1983), born Poland (possibly Warsaw)

Tags: immigration, poland, world-war-1

I am looking for my ancestry and starting on my Father's side of the family.  I am currently looking for my great great grandparents and further back on my Father's side.

My Grandpa (Father's father) is from Israel but I know that his family were originally from Poland (possibly Warsaw) I have the names of my Great Grandfather and my Great Grandmother and their dates.

- Michael Patron (Great Grandfather) 1897-1972 (said to be in WW1)
- Genia (Zeimer) Patron (Great Grandmother) 1900-1983.

They died either in Israel or South Africa.

I'm looking for Immigration documents and/or marriage licenses, birth certificates, anything that would help me delve further into my family's history

I've searched most of the obvious sites like familysearch and my heritage and I use my surname (patron) or type in an ancestors name and date of birth and death, but I only get other "Patrons" from America and such and seeing as I don't have any family in America, the search is useless. If I go onto google and type in my ancestors name it comes up with "patron saint of..." or "michael patron on facebook".

Comment: Where did the Great Grandparents die?

Comment: It's either Israel or South Africa

Comment: Daniella, if you tell us what sites you've been to and what you've searched for, we'll be better able to help.

Comment: @daniella Welcome to Genealogy and Family History SE! Because this site operates with a Q&A format, it's best if you ask for specific information rather than any information. It makes it easier for us to know what you want. Are you looking for a birth certificate? A marriage license? A death certificate? Some other piece of information?

Comment: I'm looking for Immigration documents and/or marriage licenses, birth certificates, anything that would help me delve further into my family's history

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl, I've searched most of the obvious ones like familysearch, myheritage...etc and i use my surname (patron) or type in an ancestors name and date of birth and death, but I only get other "Patrons" from America and such and seeing as I don't have any family in America, the search is useless, most times i go onto google and type in my ancestors name and it comes up with "patron saint of..." or "michael patron on facebook"

Comment: Daniella, I've added the extra information you've provided into the question and made the title more specific. If I've got anything wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 5):

In general, online records related to Jews from Poland from the 19th century are not as dense as those from Western Europe or from the US. [JewishGen](http://www.jewishgen.org/) has some related information, and you should definitely explore the [JRI-Poland](http://www.jewishgen.org/jri-pl/jriplweb.htm) database, but I would not necessarily expect to find information on arbitrary individuals.

**UPDATE**: For the record, there are quite a few people with the last name `Patron` listen on JRI-Poland, including some from the Warsaw area. I didn't see any obvious matches in my casual search, but you might find some promising leads.

Answer (score 3):

With the information provided above I'm thinking a surname change is at play. "Patron" is  defined as chosen, this does not confirm my theory but being that the person your looking for was presumably from Poland, names usually aren't that simple. Was he Jewish? This would help you find your ancestor.

http://www.yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Poland/Poland_from_1795_to_1939

The way I'd go is to track down the history by studying his migration. The records you seek will be time based. Therefore, find the events of history and search these for your ancestor. It may help to work your way backwards and search border crossings, arrival, and departure records for Israel as well as Poland, and Germany. Parrish or Synagogue records may produce valid records.

I hope this helps. : }